# OpenCv Python (CTypes) detection of tilted face

Tags: python, opencv, detection

I have a not-so-simple question.

---

**The Situation:**

I'm working on robust facial detection API in python written on top of OpenCV (cv not cv2).

I am using Haar Cascades for face detection specially

front - haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml

profile - haarcascade_profileface.xml

Each worker is using different harr classifier (front/profile) and produce the set of ROI (Region of Interests) then do a uion on them and merge all overlaping bouding boxes.

The result is "your casual red square" around a face with 70% accuracy and not so may phantom faces.

---

**The problem:**

Simply tilting the face. My algorithm cannot detect a tilted face.

For profile detection I did a simple flip of a image to detect both left and right profile.

I was thinking there "should" be a better way to detect a tilted face than to call algorithm multiple times for multiple slightly rotated images. (This is a only solution that came to my mind).

---

**The question:**

Is there a approach or a way or a specific harr classifier for detection of tilted faces?

Thank you :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [rotated face detection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015124/rotated-face-detection)